# Transport equation $u_t+c(x)u_x=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Let c $\in$ $C^1$$\mathbb(R)$. Consider the transport equation.

$u_t+c(x)u_x=0$.

Prove that if $x=f(x)$ is a characteristic curve, then so are all horizontally translated curves $ x=f(t+a)$ for any $a \in R$ and

Why a solution wave $u(t,x)$ cannot change its direction?

Can someone help me with these questions i dont now how to do it. please

Comment: Hi ramazan çalışkan and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean for $(t,f(t))$ to be a characteristic curve? It means that 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}u(t,f(t))=u_t+f'(t)u_x=0
$$
Which in your equation imposes that $f$ satisfies $f'(t)=c(f(t))$ for any $t$ in the domain.

Now take $f(t+a)$ and differentiate it to find by the chain rule
$$
f'(t+a)\frac{d}{dt}(t+a)=f'(t+a)
$$
but we assumed 
$$
f'(t+a)=c(f(t+a))
$$
so $(t,f(t+a))$ is also a characteristic curve.